# Is there a way to define list(obj) method on a user defined class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

One can can implement the method `__str__(self)` to return a string. Is there an `__list__(self)` counterpart? (`__list__` doesn't work!)
Is .toList() the way to go?

Comment: There is no magic method called `__list__`. So, you may have to live with an instance method.

Comment: What is the reason for not emulating the container type directly as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types)?

Comment: Can you post your model and what exactly it is you are trying to do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no direct counterpart, but `list()` is implemented by iterating over the argument. So implement either [the iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) (`__iter__()`) or [bound indexing](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) (`__len__()` and `__getitem__()`).

Comment: plus the fact that this makes it conformant with everything else in the language, too.

Answer (score 3):

Generator:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return (i for i in [1,5,6,8])
```

List:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter([1,5,6,8])
```

Tuple:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter((1,5,6,8))
```